# Android app crashing when using resource from an aar library (resource ID is always zero 0x0)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-library

I have updated my library project to Android Studio 4.1.0 and Android Gradle plugin 4.1.0.

It builds an aar package that contains some Android resources.

Another app includes the library and uses the resources from the aar package.

This app crashes with a

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Resource ID #0x0
```

when I try to use any of the resources from the aar library.

Answer (score 1):

Due to a change in the Android Gradle plugin behavior fields from R classes are no longer kept by default when code shrinking is enabled (Proguard/R8).

To keep your library resources after shrinking, add this to your proguard-rules.pro file:

```
# Starting from Android Gradle plugin 4.1.0 fields from R classes are no longer kept by default
-keepclassmembers class your.library.package.R$* {
   public static <fields>;
}
```

See:

- Android Gradle plugin 4.1.0: [App size significantly reduced for apps using code shrinking](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4.1-app-size-reduction)
- Google issue traker: [Resource shrinker: Avoid keeping entire R class](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142449264)